# DOMPDF Timing out when creating large PDF

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF with Laravel 5 to generate PDFs from some of my views. It works well on everything except one where it keeps timing out. The code I am using for this view is exactly the same as what I'm using for another which works fine except this one returns more results. I've tried increasing the timeout limit but this didn't help.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this? I found a few results online but they are all quite old and most of them were a bug with nested tables.

```
$TheDate = Request::input('TheDate');
    $contractor_results = DB::table('contractors')
    ->where('CurrentEmployee', '=', 1)
    ->get();
    $employee_results = DB::table('current_employees')
    ->where('CurrentEmployee', '=', 1)
    ->get();

    $sortResults = array_merge($contractor_results, $employee_results);
    $sortResults = collect($sortResults);
    $contractors = $sortResults->sortBy(function($sortResults){
        return sprintf('%-12s%s', $sortResults->SURNAME, $sortResults->NAME);
    });

    $Departments = DepartmentCode::where('ShowOnSheet', 1)
        ->orderBy('Sort', 'ASC')
        ->get();

   $pdf = PDF::loadView('attendance.contractor_sheet', compact('contractors', 'TheDate', 'Departments'))->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('portrait');
    return $pdf->stream('SignonSheet.pdf');
```

Edited to add code. If I render the view as normal without going to a PDF it works without any issues.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying please?

Comment: Since the issue isn't with the PHP code that generates the HTML it would be more instructive to see a sample of the HTML you're trying to render.

Comment: It's not an issue with the HTML either, I have another page with exactly the same HTML that renders correctly, it's just that there are fewer results to loop through on that page. I pretty much need to do something that's going to stop the browser timing out while it renders, or maybe some Javascript solution to convert the page to a pdf.

Comment: I understand that the HTML itself is not causing rendering issues. However, sometimes you can improve rendering time by tweaking your document structure.

Comment: That being said, if you don't need the PDF to render and display immediately you can fork a command-line process to run in the background and notify your user when the PDF is ready.